# converting SQL into KNEX multiple conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, knex.js

I'm trying to convert my SQL into KNEX. what I have so far is:

SQL:

`SELECT name from students where attendance = "90" AND timestamp between "2020-05-14" AND "2020-05-18";`

my attempt to convert to KNEX:

```
const from = req.query.from;
const to = req.query.to

router.get('/students/attendance?from=&to='

req.db.from('students').select("*").where('attendance', '=', req.params.attendance).andWhere('timestamp', 'between', [from, to])
```

MYSQL code works and returns what I want but I'm assuming my syntax is wrong with the Knex. Push in the right direction please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where between is documented here https://knexjs.org/#Builder-whereBetween

```
await req.db
  .from('students')
  .select("*")
  .where('attendance', req.params.attendance)
  .whereBetween('timestamp', [from, to])
```

Also you can use .toSQL() to inspect the built query query.